# Entering negative Numbers on Array

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, recursion

I am running an array that is based on a number input. It uses recursion to find the min number on the array. If the user enters 0 the program ends. It works fine until I deal with negative numbers let say I enter 0 2 3 5 3. The return comes correctly the lowest number would be 0. However If I enter 2 9 92 2 -1 0. The program does not end once I enter the 0 thusly it does not show -1 as the min number. Any suggestions or help.

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.text.*;
 public class Assignment9
 {

public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
{
        int i = 0;
    double[] NumArray;
        NumArray = new double[100];
        // input stream reader reads in keyboard inputs, while buffered reader
                        // reads in the line as a string15. 
        InputStreamReader inRead = new InputStreamReader(System.in);   
        BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(inRead);
        String line = buffRead.readLine();

        // if the string is equal to 0 and is false AND i is less than22.  
        // 100, parse string into double.23.   
        try
        {    
            while (line.equals("0") == false && i<100)      
            {       
                i++;        
                line = buffRead.readLine();     
            NumArray[i]=Double.parseDouble(line);       
            }      
            }    

        catch(IOException e) 
        {       
            System.out.println("Array index out of bound");   
            }   

double min =  findMin(NumArray, 0, NumArray.length - 1);
          System.out.print ("The minimum number is " + min + ('\n'));
         public static double findMin(double[] NumArray, int startIndex, int endIndex)
     {  
if (startIndex == endIndex) 
      { 
return NumArray[startIndex];    
       }
    else if(findMin(NumArray, startIndex, endIndex - 1) < NumArray[endIndex]) 
      { 
    return findMin(NumArray, startIndex, endIndex -1 ); 
      } 
else    
{       
    return NumArray[endIndex];
    }
            }
```

Comment: nice reverse indenting style

Comment: This code will not compile.

Comment: Please try to adhere to basic code conventions: proper indenting (probably a feature built-in to your editor), camelCase for local variables, including arrays, etc. Also does it "not end" (doesn't print anything) or does it crash? With recursion you'd get a StackOverflowException pretty quickly.

Comment: Took me like 5min to find the method `findMin()`'s declaration... XD

Comment: I fear this code can not be auto-formatted.

Comment: Just saying, you are skipping the first number the user enters. If user enters 1 2 3 4, you only save 2 3 4.

Comment: findMin() infinity loops given a negative number.

Comment: Please note that it's important that these questions be of long term use to others. Please don't edit out the code after the problem has been solved

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems.

First, you aren't storing the first number you entered into the array.  Store it unless it's `0`.

Second, even though you break out of the `while` loop when the user entered `0`, you already entered `0` into the array.  Don't enter `0` if that is meant only for the user to exit the input process.

Last, you are calling `findMin` from `findMin` *twice* when not in the base case.  There are 100 elements in the array, so you will call `findMin` up to `2^100` times!

Store the result of the recursive call, so you only call it once per recursion.  Change

```
if (startIndex == endIndex) 
      { 
return NumArray[startIndex];    
       }
else if(findMin(NumArray, startIndex, endIndex - 1) < NumArray[endIndex]) 
      { 
    return findMin(NumArray, startIndex, endIndex -1 ); 
      }
```

to

```
double min;
if (startIndex == endIndex)
{
     return NumArray[startIndex];

else if((min = findMin(NumArray, startIndex, endIndex - 1)) < NumArray[endIndex])
{
    return min;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your recursive method calls itself twice.  If you call it with an array of 100 elements, then it will call itself twice with a sub-array of 99 elements; that will call itself twice with a sub-array of 98 elements, *each time* it's called, for a total of 4 times; and so on.  The result is that the method will be called 2^100 times (2 to the 100th power)!!  Or maybe it's 2^99 or 2^101, I haven't checked.  But it's a whole lot.  That's why your program isn't stopping if there's a negative number in the array.

To solve this, rearrange your code to call `findMin` only once, and assign a variable to it, then use the value of the variable.

Other problems: When `main` calls `findMain`, it calls it with 0 and 99 as the bounds, even if you haven't entered that many numbers.  The upper bound needs to be fixed.  Finally, if you go through the code you will see that `main` never sets `NumArray[0]`; the first element it sets is `NumArray[1]`.  But the (uninitialized) value is still used in finding the minimum.  (I think it will always be 0, in Java, but in other languages doing something like this would result in a random garbage value.)